# _Context.send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'files'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, slash, discord-interactions

Im using interactions.py and I cant figure out how to respond with an image

```
await ctx.send(files="86.png")
```

Comment: please send full code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file you're trying to send, `86.png`, is in the same path as your main file, you should do this:

```
await ctx.send(file="86.png")
```

The correct parameter is `file`, not `files`.

Comment: That is discord.py.
He mentioned interactions.py, which is another Discord API wrapper that focuses on interaction based from Discord, a.k.a slash commands, components, modals, etc.

Answer (score 0):

File sending is not supported by default in Context, however, there is a 3rd party library known as [files](https://github.com/interactions-py/files) allows you to send files in `ctx` by monkeypatching the default CommandContext and ComponentContext, which adds support for the argument `files` in `ctx.send()` and `ctx.edit()`.